# While doing fetch with MovieDB my CPU goes 100% React

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to fetch some data from MovieDB API but while i am trying to do my cpu went to 100%. I console.log something at the end of my fetch and see that when i search and wanted to go to that movies details i was fetching the data of movies repeatedly. I tried to use axios but that didn't work either.

Comment: Welcome Efekan! Looks like the code is running in an [infinite loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop). Can you please share some code? In this way we can help you out detecting where exactly.

Comment: @Efekan_Efe Don't post your API key here, hide this with a placeholder variable for example when sharing the code. You don't want others to have access to your key. Also I think it's better to delete the comment and edit your question and add your code there. Also post a more complete (reproducible) version of the code, because the `onChange` function isn't enough to diagnose the problem.